# Bootstrap-confirmation not respecting options

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

Just adding the bootstrap-confirmation extension for Bootstrap popover to some buttons on a project. I'm having issues with the options not being respected. I'm trying to get the popups to work as singletons and dismiss when the user clicks outside of them `singleton` and `data-popout` options, respectively - both set to true. I'm also not seeing any of my defined callback behavior happening.

I defined the options both in the HTML tags and in a function and neither works. Still getting multiple boxes and they don't dismiss as expected.

My JS is loaded after all other libraries and is in my `custom.js` file in my footer.

JS is as follows:

```
$(function() {
    $('body').confirmation({
        selector: '[data-toggle="confirmation"]',
        singleton: true,
        popout: true
    });
    $('.confirmation-callback').confirmation({
        onConfirm: function() { alert('confirm') },
        onCancel: function() { alert('cancel') }
    });
});
```

An example of the box implemented on a button in my HTML is the following:

```
<a class="btn btn-danger" data-toggle="confirmation" data-singleton="true" data-popout="true"><em class="fa fa-trash"></em></a>
```

Any pointers would be appreciated. I even changed the default options in the `bootstrap-confirmation.js` file itself to what I want and still no luck.

Comment: Have you tried to assign the onConfirm/onCancel events when defining the confirmation options? Like this: $('body').confirmation({ onConfirm: function(event) { alert('confirm') }, ........ }); ?

Comment: @RicardoPontual that was, indeed, the gist of the problem. I got my wires crossed by using some bad example code. I've included the solution that I used below for anyone who may run in to this. Thanks for the pointer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out I needed to rearrange a couple things to get this to work. I've left in the `last_clicked_id` etc stuff as I needed to add that to get the `id` value of what I'd just clicked.

```
// Product removal popup logic
var last_clicked_id = null;
var last_clicked_product = null;
$('.btn.btn-danger.btn-confirm').click(function () {
    last_clicked_id = $(this).data("id");
    last_clicked_product = $(this).data("product");
});
$('.btn.btn-danger.btn-confirm').confirmation({
    singleton: true,
    popout: true,
    onConfirm: function () {
        alert("DEBUG: Delete confirmed for id : " + last_clicked_product);
        // TODO: Add AJAX to wipe entry and refresh page
    },
    onCancel: function () {
        alert("DEBUG: Delete canceled for id : " + last_clicked_product);
    }
});
```

I was a step ahead of myself with the callback logic which was not getting executed. Fixed by simply adding it to `onConfirm:` and `onCancel:` key values in the `.confirmation()` function. A bit of a RTFM moment there but this was unfortunately not very clear in the documentation.